# xcoffins and fractional factors to \CoffinWidth fail

Tags: xcoffins

The following code comes from this SE query: [Can I centre my oversized coffin of unknown width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374464/can-i-centre-my-oversized-coffin-of-unknown-width/374470#374470). It was posted by @cfr and accompanied by output, so, presumably, it worked at one time:

```
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade [left color=Cerulean, right color=Cerulean, middle color=MidnightBlue] (0,0) rectangle (200mm,10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,standalone,tikz,xcoffins,calc}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\TestCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\TestCoffin{\input{pic}}

\MarkCoffinHandle\TestCoffin[hc,vc]{magenta}
\MarkCoffinHandle\TestCoffin[l,vc]{magenta}

Can I centre the coffin \emph{without} knowing the width of the picture?

This works:\par
\noindent
\TypesetCoffin\TestCoffin[l,vc](-.5\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin+.5\textwidth,0pt)
\bigskip

This doesn't:\par
{\centering
  \TypesetCoffin\TestCoffin[hc,vc]\par}


\end{document}
```

When I run that code now, it fails with the following error:

```
./Coffin_mwe_001.tex:22: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   .
l.22 ...5\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin+.5\textwidth,0pt)
```

If I delete the fractional factor `.5` from  `-.5\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin` to make it `-\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin/2` then the code works, though division by non-integers, not surprisingly, does not work. Note also that **integer** factors to `\CoffinWidth` also work correctly.

I cannot seem to find discussion of this on SE. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Easiest way to centre almost anything without knowing its width: `\begin{center}\makebox[0pt][c]{<almost anything>}\end{center}`. Most likely this results from the parsing rules of `\dimexpr`. Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr/245663#245663).

Comment: My question is not about centering anything, but about non-integer factors to `\CoffinWidth`. I'll make my question more specific.

Comment: You can give a non-integer factor with `.5\dimexpr\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin\relax` as a workaround.

Comment: Odd. Well, make it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `\CoffinWidth` expands to `\dim_eval:n { \coffin_wd:N #1 }`. `\dim_eval:n` expands to `\dim_use:N \__dim_eval:w #1\__dim_eval_end:` which is the same as `\the\dimexpr#1\relax`. And you can't use a factor on `\the`. So we have to somehow turn this back into something where we can use a factor on. That something can be a `\dimexpr` without a `\the` before it.

Comment: OK, but **integer factors** do work correctly. Again, odd.

Comment: I should also point out that TeX is having a problem with the `.`. Neither the `-` nor the number seem to be the problem.

Comment: Just wait a few more minutes, I'm formulating a longish answer...

Comment: Just to be clear: If I say `-2\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin` the code TeXs so the problem would seem to be **fractional factors**. The `\dimexpr` trick does work.

Comment: I know, now **wait**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explanation why it doesn't work:

`\CoffinWidth` is defined as `\dim_eval:n { \coffin_wd:N #1 }`. `\dim_eval:n` expands to `\dim_use:N \__dim_eval:w #1\__dim_eval_end:` so the above becomes `\dim_use:N \__dim_eval:w \coffin_wd:N #1\__dim_eval_end:`. That is (removing the l3 nomenclature) the same as `\the\dimexpr\wd#1\relax`.

You're using that inside of the optional argument of `\TypesetCoffin` which is again a `\dimexpr` so something like `\dimexpr\the\dimexpr\wd\TestCoffin\relax\relax`. In the following I'll drop the outer `\dimexpr` occasionally, I hope it is still understandable.

`\the\dimexpr\wd#1\relax` would expand to something like `<float>pt`. In the following let us assume that `<float>` is the (rather unspectacular) float `1.0`. Note that `\the\<dimen>` always returns a period even if it won't make a different (so if the only decimal digit is a 0). Now with our example we take a look at what happens if you precede it with a factor:

Choosing an integer factor (let's take `2`) what you get is `21.0pt`, which is valid but certainly not the double of `1.0pt`. Using another float as the factor (let's take `0.5`) you get `0.51.0pt` which is not a valid length, hence the error.

What do we do now? One way would be to use a division with an integer of 2 (putting back the outer `\dimexpr` and replacing the inner one with our exemplary `1.0pt`): `\dimexpr 1.0pt/2\relax` is valid input. Another way would be to use multiplication, again only with integers: `\dimexpr1.0pt*2\relax` is still valid. But what if we want to use a float as the factor? We have to turn the thing back into something TeX considers a dimen, which is why we use `\dimexpr` around the inner expression: `.5\dimexpr 1.0pt\relax` is again valid.

## Turning it into a working bit of code that does the intended thing:

With the wrapping of `\dimexpr` we considered a viable solution above your code becomes:

```
\TypesetCoffin\TestCoffin[l,vc](-.5\dimexpr\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin\relax+.5\textwidth,0pt)
```

And we're done. Complete MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade [left color=Cerulean, right color=Cerulean, middle color=MidnightBlue] (0,0) rectangle (200mm,10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,standalone,tikz,xcoffins,calc}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\TestCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\TestCoffin{\input{pic}}

\MarkCoffinHandle\TestCoffin[hc,vc]{magenta}
\MarkCoffinHandle\TestCoffin[l,vc]{magenta}

Can I centre the coffin \emph{without} knowing the width of the picture?

This works:\par
\noindent
\TypesetCoffin\TestCoffin[l,vc](-.5\dimexpr\CoffinWidth\TestCoffin\relax+.5\textwidth,0pt)
\bigskip

This doesn't:\par
{\centering
  \TypesetCoffin\TestCoffin[hc,vc]\par}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope the description does not only make sense in my own brain...

Comment: I understand and have accepted your answer, and, moreover, I have a workaround -- mission accomplished. The only lingering question I have is why, in 2017, did something like `0.5\CoffinWidth` work? Was that an error? A fluke?

Comment: @sgmoye I don't know for sure, as I don't like to investigate it atm, but I guess there was a change in the underlying macros or in `\CoffinWidth`. With the knowledge from the first paragraph in my answer (that `\CoffinWidth` is essentially `\the\dimexpr\wd#1\relax`) one could as well just use `.5\wd\TestCoffin` as a solution, but I don't know whether this would still work in the distant future but I hope that the used workaround (adding `\dimexpr...\relax`) will still work in a reasonable amount of time from now on.